# get broken pipe while uploading image to s3 amazon using paper clip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I get a broken pipe error while uploading image to s3 amazon using paper clip

My Model:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => "100x100#", :large => "500x500>" },
                    :processors => [:cropper],
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                    :path => "/:style/:id/:filename",
                    :bucket => "shahbunder"
```

My s3.yml:

```
development:
  bucket: xxx
  access_key_id: xxx
  secret_access_key: xxx
test:
  bucket: xxx
  access_key_id: xxx
  secret_access_key: xxx
production:
  bucket: xxx
  access_key_id: xxx
  secret_access_key: xxx
```

Answer (score 4):

Note for people searching for a solution to an error that crosses between this and ERRCONNRESET - Response time skewed - your server clock is not synchronized with Amazon correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you type your bucket name using "/" (ex: "bucket_name/"), use only the name (ex: "bucket_name").

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is usually because your s3 credentials are wrong. But here are 2 different things you can try:

1. script/plugin install git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git (installing paperclip as a plugin instead of a gem has helped some)
2. gem install right_aws right_http_connection (make sure you are firing off your request correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Fog instead, I don't know if it's still undocumented or what:

Example (fit to your needs):

```
has_attached_file :media,
  storage:         :fog,
  hash_secret:     Settings.aws.uploader.hash_secret,
  use_timestamp:   Settings.aws.uploader.use_timestamps_in_url,
  fog_credentials: Settings.aws.uploader.fog.to_hash,
  fog_public:      Settings.aws.uploader.public_files,
  fog_directory:   Settings.aws.s3.bucket_cname,
  fog_host:        "http://s.my.com",
  default_url:     "media/system/not_available.mp3",
  hash_data:       ":class/:attachment/:id/:style/:updated_at",
  path:            ":root_path/:id_partition",
  #only_process:
  processors: [:audio_thumbnail],
  styles: { small: ['36x36#', :jpg], medium: ['72x72#', :jpg], large: ['115x115#', :jpg] },
  skip_updated_at: true
```